# Временная смена потока в RxJS или отслеживание обрыва соединения с сервером в Websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, rxjs

Есть код, который обрабатывает данные приходящие с сервера через WebSockets и помещает их в state. Данные приходят непрерывно. Данные отображаются в виде шкалы. Нужно сделать так, что бы если соединение с сервером оборвалось, данные с сервера менялись бы на фейковые данные на клиенте, где грубо говоря есть нулевые данные, что бы шкала обнулялась на время обрыва соединения. А после восстановление соединения источником данных снова становился WS. 
Можно ли это как то сделать посредствам RxJS или без обработки событий обрыва и восстановления соединения ничего не получится? И если только вариант с обработкой обрыва соединения сработает, то как лучше это сделать?

```js
WS.join(ROOM).pipe(
  map(actions.setMeters),
)
```

Comment: что именно ты используешь в качестве апи - `window.WebSocket` или `rx.WebSocketSubject`?

Comment: Использую socket-io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как примерно это можно решить.

```js
const ws$ = interval(500).pipe( // представим что interval - это наш сокет
  take(8), // возьмём только первые 8 значений. Этот оператор не важен, он только для наглядности
  map(x => {  // при помощи map сэмитируем разрыв соединиения   
    if (Math.random() < 0.3) {
      throw 'Error';
    }

    return x;
  }),
  catchError(() => ws$.pipe(startWith('s'))) // вот тут происходит самое интересное,
  // как только соединение разывается, мы стартуем наше соединение по новой,
  // но перед этим выводим "нулевое" значние при помощи startWith.
);

ws$;
```

Вот тут можно увидеть этот пример в действии https://rxviz.com/v/dJBZPD1J